# Two particles colliding head on with each moving at almost the speed of light -- how long does it take vs one stationary?

Tags: special-relativity, velocity

I believe that an observer on one of the particles would see the other particle moving not at nearly twice the speed of light but only at roughly the speed of light.

But surely the time it takes for the two particles to collide for a human observer who knows when each particle was shot out of an accelerator and can tell when the collision occurs is half the time it would take if one particle was stationary relative to the observer (maybe it is held at the half-way point) and only the other is moving relative to the observer at near light speed.

That is to say, the observer sees the collision of two moving particles occurring at almost twice the speed of light. Or is this wrong because of Special Relativity?

What about kinetic energy? Is it the same or different in the two situations?

EDIT:

If the two particles are one light second apart and one is stationary, the outside observer sees the collision occurring after one second.

If the particles are both moving at C, I can't see why the collision does not occur in half a second.

Except: That would mean that information could be sent faster than light to an observer on either particle. But the outside observer gets no information faster than light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the frame of the stationary observer, the two particles approach each other at a speed which is greater than c. However, in the frame of either particle, the closing speed is less than c.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i got the question

Say two humans, a proper distance $L$, shot each other. The time it takes to the particles hit themselves is given by

$$v_1 t = L - v_2 t \Rightarrow t = \frac{L}{v_1 + v_2}$$

The shooters didn't see the particles moving with $v_1 + v_2$, they see them moving with their normal velocity :/. Now, this is not a relativity problem, in Newtonian mechanics we didn't see the particles moving with $v_1 + v_2$ as well!

If you are asking about the velocity each particle see each other, the simplest formula (parallel velocity) would be

$$v_{rel} = \frac{v_1 + v_2}{1 + \frac{v_1 v_2}{c^2}}$$

for $v_1 \approx v_2 \approx c$,

$$v_{rel} \approx \frac{c + c}{1 + \frac{c^2}{c^2}} = \frac{2c}{2} = c$$

So each particle still see the next one moving in its direction with speed near $c$

Answer (score 0):

I see this about "closing speeds" [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faster-than-light#:~:text=Closing%20speeds,-The%20rate%20at&text=The%20closing%20speed%20would%20be,relativity%20does%20not%20prohibit%20this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faster-than-light#:%7E:text=Closing%20speeds,-The%20rate%20at&text=The%20closing%20speed%20would%20be,relativity%20does%20not%20prohibit%20this).

This says that the observer of both particles can see them "closing" faster than light -- that is to say, the collision occurs as if one particle were stationary and the other was moving faster than light. The observers on the particles don't see the other as moving FTL because than they could get a message before a radio signal, etc. was received, but the laboratory observer, watching both particles, does not get any signal FTL.

Answer (score 0):

The [relativistic velocity addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula) formula is $$u' = \frac{u+v}{1+\frac{uv}{c^2}},$$
that is, for high velocities the denominator keeps everything under lightspeed. So in the case where one particle moves at speed $v$ and one with speed $-v$, as seen from an observer moving at speed $v$ they see velocities $2v/(1+v^2/c^2)$ and 0.

If the particles move along a track of length L, the stationary observer sees them pass across it in time $L/2v$ (a 2 since both are moving). The moving observer would say they traverse distance $L$ in time $L(1+v^2/c^2)/2v$... which seems slower.

But the *track* will also be length contracted since it is moving in the view of that observer, who sees a track of length $L\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$. So the time taken in their frame for the particles to cross the track will actually be $L\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}(1+v^2/c^2)/2v$. So at very high speed the time along the track will seem surprisingly short.

The stationary observer, on the other hand, will note that the moving observer is reacting slowly due to time dilation, so they will say the reason for the measured time is a slowed clock.

In the limit of lightspeed signals, the moving photon observer will simply not experience any time and the entire world is from their perspective squashed flat: everything happens simultaneously according to them.